# Disable Discord dock badge

Tags: macos, icons, dock, voice-chat, discord

I'm using the Discord app for Mac. The app icon in the dock has a red badge on it at all times.

[image: Badge on Discord dock icon]

The badge looks like the ones that indicate new messages on apps like Mail, Messages, etc, only instead of a number, it displays just a dot.

There are no new/unread messages or notifications for me in Discord, as far as I can tell. When I receive new messages, the badge doesn't change. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with voice recording or push-to-talk either.

I've searched the app settings, but the only notification-related item I could find was toggling the desktop notifications on/off.

What is the meaning of this badge, and how can I turn it off?

Comment: Whatever it is, it's extremely annoying.

Comment: I talked to Discord tech support, and got the answer that the badge can't be permanently disabled. It will disappear iff all conversation are marked as read, until the next unread entry appears. I'd answer the question myself, but I'm curious about Wouter van Eekelen's solution, which I can't reproduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discord also doesn't show up for me in System Preferences -> Notifications, however there are two places where Discord notification settings are, both accessible from the app.

From the top ribbon, click Discord > Preferences and there's a Notifications menu. From there you can disable Desktop notifications.

Additionally, if you right click each channel you're in you can see the per-channel notification settings.

Finally, in order to actually clear the badge after I turned notifications off, I right clicked each channel and clicked "Mark as read".

Comment: This did the trick! I'd like to add that for this I had to mute all of my channels, even the ones that didn't have any unread messages.

Answer (score 8):

It usually means you have an unread message in a channel. You can disable it by going to your System Preferences -> Notifications -> Discord -> Uncheck the "Badge app icon".

[image: Notification Settings]

Comment: Discord doesn't show up in my notifications settings. Any idea what's up with that? I'm using Discord version 0.0.246 on Sierra.

Comment: I created a new question about locating the settings: http://superuser.com/questions/1130873/where-are-the-discord-notification-settings-located

Comment: You need to add Discord to applications. I assume you might be running it directly from the Installer.dmg

Comment: ty ty, worked, why doesn't discord allow you to disable from inside the app?

Comment: My Discord is in Applications, and that's where I'm running it from, but Settings > "Notifications & Focus" does not show Discord in the list on the left. I'd love to get rid of this annoying ever-present red badge. Why is Discord not appearing in Mac Settings?

Comment: @Ryan check the more recent answers, this is now a part of Discord's settings!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in any of the servers you are part of tags @everyone, then there'll be a notification.
Literally the only time the dot badge disappears for me is if I mute every server for x hours.
Doesn't matter if you've set notifications to Only @ Mentions.

Also, make sure you go to your Inbox tray icon and tick all Unreads, and change the settings for Mentions to *not* Include @everyone mentions.

Discord is rough if you are a server manager, cos you literally cannot use the dock icon to just see important messages on your own server unless everything else is muted.

Answer (score 0):

Discord now seems to have a setting to disable this useless badge icon!

Go to Discord > Settings > App Settings > Notifications > Enable Unread Message Badge:

[image]