# Where are the Discord notification settings located?

Tags: macos, icons, dock, voice-chat, discord

I'm trying to locate the notification settings for the macOS Discord app; specifically I'm trying to disable the app icon badge. I've been asking about the badge in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1078723/disable-discord-dock-badge), and one of the answers there pointed me to the system preferences, *System Preferences > Notifications > Discord*, even providing a picture of the setting.

In the notifications settings on my Mac, there is no entry for Discord.

I've been looking through the notifications settings within the Discord app, but there's no mention of the app icon badge.

I'm using Discord 0.0.246 on Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

This icon only appears when activity is detected within servers you do *not* have muted. If you routinely get annoyed by this icon from a specific server you don't particularly care for, you can right click the server's icon, hover over "Mute Server," and choose a duration to mute the server for. "Until I turn it off again" keeps it muted permanently.

For a more global solution, there's a setting in the Discord app itself called "Enable Unread Message Badge" located within the User Settings > App Settings > Notifications directory.

Here's a screenshot of the specific toggle button you should look for:

[image: Notification setting]

Toggling this off should ensure you never see that dreaded red circle on your task bar again.